# Jest globalSetup function

Tags: typescript, mongodb, jestjs

I am attempting to use `globalSetup` with Jest to establish my database connection via the following code:

```
import { mongoConnect } from "../../server/services/mongo";

export default async () => {
  console.log('Connecting to DB!\n\n\n')
  await mongoConnect()
}
```

However, when I go to run my code each of my test suites has one failing test which is always the first that runs.  I'm assuming this is due to the fact that the first test in each suite starts running before the DB connection is complete and as such results in a failing test.

Is there anyway to configure Jest to wait for this export function before starting any tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html#globalsetup-and-globalteardown):

> #### `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown`
>
> Do not use `globalSetup` to call `mongoose.connect()` or
> `mongoose.createConnection()`. Jest runs globalSetup in a separate
> environment, so you cannot use any connections you create in
> `globalSetup` in your tests.

Initiating mongoose connection to database won't work in `globalSetup` or `globalTeardown`

Comment: Please don't include text content as images